# Adding img to div as a background

Tags: html, css, image

What should be the proper style for the IMG in order to work as a background for the Div?  I don't want to use CSS to set the background on div because I will have many LI with different DIVS and images every time.

```
<li class="container">
    <div class="inside"> some elements 
       <img src="some image"></img>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: maybe add img - position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position it with respect to the parent with `position: absolute`
To view the contents on top, I have used a priority `z-index: 1` for the span element.

```css
.inside {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<li class="container">
  <div class="inside"><span>Some Elements</span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would still use CSS, but inline:

```
<li class="container" style="background-image:url(image.jpg) top left no-repeat">
```

Using an image tag for background is poor semantic.

Answer (score 2):

Hei!
The style for IMG in order to work as a background for the DIV:

```
.inside{position:relative;}
img{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:-1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
<div class="div_img">

</div>
```

And css:

```
.img{
background-image: url('../images/div_img.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive following can help, (without separate CSS)

```
    <div class="inside" style="background-image:url('xyz.jpg');height:xypx; width=xzpx;">
</div>
```